# Chart.js - Callback to make a point active

Tags: callback, chart.js, points

I'm trying to navigate radar's graph point with the rotating bezel on watch and have stacked for several days on this:

A) Via click on graph

1. Select point (mark blue)
2. Write value to a HTML element

B) Via callback (inner circle in this sample)

1. Navigate the point +1 / -1 from A1
2. Write value to a HTML element (how to retrieve info from tooltip here?)

I have a trouble with B. In my case, B1 is navigating through points, but it **doesn't mark the point** with blue circle. It is also possible to show tooltip here correctly, but it **doesn't write to HTML element** like A1 does.

Can you help me please with B1 and B2 please? It's at the end of JS file in Fiddle sample - https://jsfiddle.net/Konvas/aqyrsxL3/22/

```
function updateView() {
  chart.tooltip._active = [chart.getDatasetMeta(currentDatasetIndex).data[currentPointIndex]];
  console.log(chart.tooltip);
  chart.tooltip.update();
  chart.update();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I thank you for your question. It helped me solve my problem. I was stuck on how to set the tooltip manually and your code worked perfectly. I did try to solve your problem. But, I cant clearly understand what you need. But I am really happy that you asked the question.